# tcpdump file size == traffic size?

Tags: tcpdump, packet-sniffer, sniffing

I created a tcpdump file:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 host xxx.208.xxx.59 -n -s 0 -vvv -w /tmp/dump.dmp
```

duration was about 3 hours.

This file now has 450 MB. Can I say now that the IP xxx.208.xxx.59 generated 450 MB traffic in 3 hours?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, maybe, not necessarily.

A pcap file is not simply a byte-for-byte representation of the traffic that was sent/received.  Things that will contribute to inaccuracies include:

- pcap file overhead.  Every packet is timestamped, for instance.
- Impedance mismatch between pcap's idea of a "packet" and your understanding of what constitutes a "packet".  The pcap file will have everything including the link-layer header, which is rarely considered part of a customer's traffic allowance for billing purposes.
- Missing packets.  The pcap layer makes no assurances that all packets will actually be transferred into tcpdump's gentle care.  Many packets may have been dropped (for a variety of reasons), and they won't be a part of the count you see.

If you want to account for traffic, do it properly, with port or netflow statistics retrieved from your core.

Comment: thx. so you mean just adding a port, for example port 110 to the tcpdump comment?

Comment: @Danzzz - no, he means performing your accounting on **switch ports**. This has nothing to do with IP ports.

Answer (score 1):

I would say yes.  As it is my understanding the writer (-w) writes the packets byte-for-byte to /tmp/dump.dmp.  But I'm only 80% sure...

That would include header information also, but that should be calculated into the throughput statistic.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of this before, but it's also worth mentioning that the "-n" and "-vvv" is unnecessary until you read (-r) the /tmp/dump.dmp.  Not sure about the "-s" so I usually leave it in.  I've not run into a situation where it was totally necessary.